custom logic in CubeJS query
I am making a data service that in part does some interesting probabilistic entity resolution. Reading through the docs, I can not quite tell how I could implement state machine-like logic in fulfilling a query to CubeJS. Is this outside the theory of use or can you share a reference to an example?
